# Duvida sobre comando list(zip) e conversão de dicionários para dataframes?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas, dataframe

Estou preenchendo algumas listas com entradas strings e outras numéricas e usando-as para preencher alguns dicionários com informações que preciso visualizar de forma alternada.
Eis que me surgiu a dúvida, o comando `list(zip())` cria diversos dicionários associados a uma variável que eu posso acessar?

Consequentemente, posso associar uma variável a cada combinação de listas que eu queira? É possível converter esses dicionários em dataframes?

```
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
list(zip(A,B))
list(zip(B,C))
list(zip(A,C))
list(zip(A,B,C))
```

Comment: Só um detalhe: segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip),  `zip` não retorna um dicionário, e sim um iterador de tuplas. Então se você faz `zip(A, B)`, ele retorna um iterador que, a cada iteração, retorna uma tupla contendo um elemento de `A` e outro de `B`. Ao fazer `list(zip(A, B))`, você tem uma lista com todas essas tuplas ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/OUjkRp) um exemplo). O que o pandas faz é usar essas tuplas para criar o dataframe, e nem precisa de `list`, pode usar só `zip` direto, [veja](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/AbsoluteUltimateEvaluations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. É possível converter dicionários em `DataFrames`. Na verdade, um dicionário com strings como chaves e valores como lista é uma forma pré-pronta de um pandas `DataFrame`. Com um dicionário no formato citado, basta usar o constructor `pd.DataFrame` para criar o dataframe. Exemplo:

```py
import pandas as pd

data_dict={"Name":["Walter", "Saul", "Hank", "Sjyler"], "Age":[54,56,48,42], "Sex":["M","M","M","F"]}

pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

Output:

```
     Name  Age Sex
0  Walter   54   M
1    Saul   56   M
2    Hank   48   M
3  Sjyler   42   F
```

Como você notou, também é possível fazer isso usando a combinação do *constructor* de lista (`list()`) com o generator `zip`. No entanto, nesse caso, você precisa explicitar o nome das colunas. Exemplo:

```py
names=["Walter", "Saul", "Hank", "Sjyler"]
age=[54,56,48,42]                                                                                                                                                                                   
sex=["M","M","M","F"]                                                                                                                                                                               

pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names,age,sex)), columns=["Name", "Age", "Sex"])
```

Ouput:

```
     Name  Age Sex
0  Walter   54   M
1    Saul   56   M
2    Hank   48   M
3  Sjyler   42   F
```

Caso você não explicite o nome das colunas, o comando também funciona, mas  o nome das colunas será o *default*: `[1,2,3]`.

Um informação adicional sobre a função `zip`. Essa função aplica uma espécie de distributiva nas listas para criar uma série tuples. Ela pertence à classe dos `generators` que são objetos usados para iteração, mas que, diferentemente de outros objetos utilizados para iteração, como *list comprehensions*, não geram um resultado. Por não não produzirem resultado, esses objetos usam menos memória. No seu caso específico, você só viu o resultado da função `zip` porque usou o `list` constructor.

Tudo isso para dizer que, embora seja possível, a construção de dataframes a partir de funções zip talvez não seja o procedimento mais comum. Usar dicionários me parece mais natural e mais simples.

Comment: Deixe-me tirar uma última dúvida, no caso, ao o comando list(zip()) para unificar as listas, estou restrito apenas a exibi-las de acordo com a ordem que escolhi na disposição das listas.

E ao usar pd.DataFrame(list(zip(...)) eu apenas posso exibir o Dataframe? 

Estou perguntando isso porque notei que ele não mostra o DataFrame gerado no console de variáveis.
 mas existe a possibilidade de convertê-lo para uma variável que eu posso manipular?
Como as listas sou eu que insiro manualmente, faz mais sentido usar o primeiro método, porém apenas para aproveitar a dúvida

Comment: Na verdade, nesse caso você gera o `DataFrame` do mesmo jeito, com a diferença que os nomes das colunas serão 1, 2, 3. Vou editar para deixar claro que o argument `columns` é opcional