# Como posso uma linha em um dataframe do Pandas a partir uma lista que contem variáveis?

Tags: python, pandas, data.frame

Então pessoal, estou com um problema que basicamente funciona de forma simplificada assim

```
# Eu criei um DataFrame a partir do pandas
import pandas as pd
Colunas = ["A","B","C","D"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = Colunas)
```

E vamos dizer que eu tenho uma lista de valores iniciais

```
DadosIniciais = [X,Y,Z,W]
```

onde XYZW são valores float que surgem de operações matemáticas simples.  Qual seria o método mais eficaz para adicionar essa lista de valores XYZW como a primeira linha do DataFrame?

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é criar o DataFrame a partir de um dicionário de listas, como indicado nesta [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484754/duvida-sobre-comando-listzip-e-convers%C3%A3o-de-dicion%C3%A1rios-para-dataframes/484757#484757).

Para o seu caso, teríamos:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
Colunas = ["A","B","C","D"]
X=random.random()
Y=random.random()
Z=random.random()
W=random.random()
Dadosiniciais=[X,Y,Z,W]

df = pd.DataFrame({k:[v] for k, v in zip(Colunas,Dadosiniciais)})

print(df)
```

Retorna:

```
          A         B         C         D
0  0.437675  0.321801  0.847752  0.480337
```